# Segmentation fault from fgets

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I've debugged the heck out of this and cannot figure why my fgets is not working. Before I changed my code such that it dynamically resizes arrays, fgets works perfectly well. As I am a beginner in C, this problem has baffled me for quite a long time.

Here is the faulty code:

```
int readNumbers(int **array, char* fname, int hexFlag) {
    int numberRead = 0;
    FILE* fp;
    int counter = 0;
    char arr[100];
    char* ptr;
    size_t curSize = 16;
    int radix = hexFlag ? 16 : 10;

    *array = malloc(0 * sizeof(*array));

    fp = fopen(fname, "r");  

    if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening file\n");
            return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(arr, sizeof(arr), fp)) { //Seg faults here when it reaches end of file.
            ptr = strtok(arr, " \n");
            while(ptr) {
                if (counter >= curSize) {
                     curSize += 16;
                     array = realloc(*array, curSize * sizeof(**array));
                }
                (*array)[counter++] = strtol(ptr, NULL, radix);
                ++numberRead;
                ptr = strtok(NULL , " \n");
            }

    }
    if (ferror(fp)) {
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
    }
```

Here is the working code before the changes to make the array resize:

```
int readNumbers(int array[], char* fname, int hexFlag) {
    int numberRead = 0;
    FILE* fp;
    int counter = 0;
    char arr[100];
    char* ptr;

    fp = fopen(fname, "r");  

    if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening file\n");
            return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(arr, sizeof(arr), fp)) {
            ptr = strtok(arr, " \n");
            while(ptr) {
               if (hexFlag == 0) { 
                    array[counter++] = strtol(ptr , NULL , 10);
               } else {
                    array[counter++] = strtol(ptr, NULL, 16);
               }
               ++numberRead;
               ptr = strtok(NULL , " \n");
            }

    }
    if (ferror(fp)) {
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
    }
```

The newly added changes seg faults when the end of file is reached. I strongly suspect that this has to do with the double pointers. Any help is strongly appreciated!

Comment: did you think it will work ..? `*array = malloc(0 * sizeof(*array));`

Comment: @AmitSharma Ah! I see, that fixed it! But I don't understand how that would cause fgets to seg fault only at the end of file instead of immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't went through whole code. But `*array = malloc(0 * sizeof(*array))` here this `malloc` call will not allocate any memory.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the problem Amit Sharma pointed out:

You initially allocate your dynamic array using:

```
*array = malloc(0 * sizeof(*array));
```

And when you store into the dynamic array, you use:

```
(*array)[counter++] = strtol(ptr, NULL, radix);
```

However, your subsequent reallocations use:

```
array = realloc(*array, curSize * sizeof(**array));
```

which should likely be:

```
*array = realloc(*array, curSize * sizeof(*array));
```

Note that it's OK (unusual, but not unheard of) to use `malloc(0)`, as long as your code is prepared to deal with a `NULL` pointer return or an allocation that can't be read from or written to.